# Why is my user input returning null in main method?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, null

I'm new to Java and this is about to make me tear my hair out. Please note I added a print statement to ensure that Scanner was working correctly.

```
package dknowlton_program5;

import java.util.Scanner;

//Driver ~ Gathers Input

public class DKnowlton_MartianMaker {

static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String name;
public static int eyes, arms;

public static void main(String[] String)
{

    printWelcome();
    getName();
    getEyes();
    getArms();

    System.out.print("Your martian " + name + " has... ");

}

public static void printWelcome()
{

    System.out.print("Welcome to the Martian Program Revamped!");

}

public static String getName()
{

    System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to name your martian? ");
    String name = userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.println(name);

    return name;

}

public static int getEyes()
{

    System.out.print("How many eyes does your martian have? ");
    int eyes = userInput.nextInt();

    return eyes;

}

public static int getArms()
{

    System.out.print("How many arms does your martian have? ");
    int arms = userInput.nextInt();

    return arms;

}

}
```

Comment: You're not assigning any of the return values to variables. **within the main method**

Comment: e.g., `name = getName();`

Comment: You may be confused in that you're using variables of the same name within your methods, but the variables declared in methods are **local** variables and are visible within the method only. Changing them will have no effect on the class fields that you've declared at the top. This is well explained in the first chapters or two of most intro to Java books.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels when I added the return value and run the program it repeats the getName() method then with no spaces prints out print statement in the main method. However, now null is replaces with a blank space rather than the user input variable. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. Notice that the static variables at the top have been removed, and instead we now save the results that are returned from the functions.
I'd suggest reading up about scope in java, in general it's best to have the lowest level of scope possible, avoid global variables were possible.

```
package dknowlton_program5;

import java.util.Scanner;

//Driver ~ Gathers Input

public class DKnowlton_MartianMaker {

static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] String)
{

    printWelcome();
    String name = getName();
    int eyes = getEyes();
    int arms = getArms();

    System.out.print("Your martian " + name + " has... ");

}

public static void printWelcome()
{

    System.out.print("Welcome to the Martian Program Revamped!");

}

public static String getName()
{

    System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to name your martian? ");
    String name = userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.println(name);

    return name;

}

public static int getEyes()
{

    System.out.print("How many eyes does your martian have? ");
    int eyes = userInput.nextInt();

    return eyes;

}

public static int getArms()
{

    System.out.print("How many arms does your martian have? ");
    int arms = userInput.nextInt();

    return arms;

}

}
```

Comment: No the same problem exists mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine. You need to adjust the print statement at the top to include the eyes and arms. Other than that it works.
What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `System.out.print("Your martian " + name + " has... ");`
shouldn't you use `System.out.println("Your Martian " + getName() + " has... ");`

Hope it works.

EDIT: Why did you declare the String name twice?

SECOND EDIT: Try this

```
package dknowlton_program5;

import java.util.Scanner;

//Driver ~ Gathers Input

public class DKnowlton_MartianMaker {

Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public String name;
public static int eyes, arms;

public static void main(String[] String)
{
DKnowlton_MartianMaker start = new DKnowlton_MartianMaker();
    start.printWelcome();
    start.getName();
    start.getEyes();
    start.getArms();

    System.out.print("Your martian " + getName() + " has... ");

}

public void printWelcome()
{

    System.out.print("Welcome to the Martian Program Revamped!");

}

public String getName()
{

    System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to name your martian? ");
    name = userInput.nextLine();

    System.out.println(name);

    return name;

}

public int getEyes()
{

    System.out.print("How many eyes does your martian have? ");
    int eyes = userInput.nextInt();

    return eyes;

}

public int getArms()
{

    System.out.print("How many arms does your martian have? ");
    int arms = userInput.nextInt();

    return arms;

}
```

}

Comment: Instead of declaring all of you methods static, I used an object and called the methods from there.

Comment: -WUB WUB m8 you there?

Comment: Sorry about that I'm just getting really frustrated as my teacher made this due Saturday because she messed up scheduling and I have to work.

Comment: Anyways where did I declare String name twice?

Comment: Before the main class, you declared the variable name, and in the get name method, you declared it again.

Answer (score 0):

this "Name" :

```
public static String name;
```

is differnt form this "Name" :

```
String name = userInput.nextLine();
```

- you assign the value to the second one , and print the first one , that is why you get null.
- you can simply remove the String and use the same "name " you define at beginning (the first one) :

  ```
  package dknowlton_program5;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  //Driver ~ Gathers Input

  public class DKnowlton_MartianMaker {

  static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static String name;
  public static int eyes, arms;

  public static void main(String[] String)
  {

      printWelcome();
      getName();
      getEyes();
      getArms();

      System.out.print("Your martian " + name + " has... ");

  }

  public static void printWelcome()
  {

      System.out.print("Welcome to the Martian Program Revamped!");

  }

  public static String getName()
  {

      System.out.print("\nWhat would you like to name your martian? ");
      name = userInput.nextLine();

      System.out.println(name);

      return name;

  }

  public static int getEyes()
  {

      System.out.print("How many eyes does your martian have? ");
      int eyes = userInput.nextInt();

      return eyes;

  }

  public static int getArms()
  {

      System.out.print("How many arms does your martian have? ");
      int arms = userInput.nextInt();

      return arms;

  }

  }
  ```